# How a write a SQL function that take two date parameters and returns a new table? Is this the correct way to write

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
USE databasename
GO
CREATE function fx_explodedates_by date
( @datestart smalldatetime,
  @dateend smalldatetime )
RETURNS @daterange TABLE
 ( 
   tenant id nchar(5),
   salutation nchar(10)
   forename nvarchar(20)
   surname nvarchar(20)
   startdate (yyyy-mm-dd)
   enddate (yyyy-mm-dd)
   )

AS
BEGIN
INSERTt @daterange 
SELECT tenant id, salutation, forename,surname,startdate,enddate 
FROM tablename
WHERE date between @datestart and @dateend

END
```

Comment: You will not be able to write one function for both MySQL and SQL Server...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for SQL Server (based on syntax) your function is almost correct - apart from typographical errors and datatype syntax errors you're just missing a `return` statement.

The function should probably look something like this:

```
CREATE function fx_explodedates_by_date
( @datestart smalldatetime,
  @dateend smalldatetime )
RETURNS @daterange TABLE
 ( 
   tenant_id nchar(5),
   salutation nchar(10),
   forename nvarchar(20),
   surname nvarchar(20),
   startdate date,
   enddate date
   )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT @daterange (tenant_id, salutation, forename, surname, startdate, enddate)
    SELECT tenant_id, salutation, forename, surname, startdate, enddate 
    FROM tablename
    WHERE [date] between @datestart and @dateend
    RETURN 
END
```

It's a bit unclear what your table actually looks like so you will probably have to change the column names and types to match what they're actually are (I was guessing a bit).